# Prevent numbers from breaking on 1000 separator

Tags: html, css, word-break

There's a table in a HTML file. The `word-break` CSS attribute indicates that long words have to break inside that table. I want only long texts (and not numbers) to break. I have some numbers, which have 1000 separators (every three digits, there's a comma). Those numbers break, too. 

Is there any way to prevent those numbers from breaking ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<span style="white-space: nowrap;">Content</span>`. Alternatively, wrap your numbers inside a `<nobr>`-tag, note that this tag is not a standard though!

Comment: Why are you giving the obsolete solution first? Which browser does not support `white-space`?

Comment: Because I am hoping that the <nobr>-tag will sometime in the near future receive more attention and become a standard.

Comment: It won't. It's obsolete.